Does the SpaceX Crew Dragon need any modifications for circumlunar flight?
Does it need upgraded heat shields, communication gear, or anything else? Or can we just put it on a Falcon Heavy and do it now?

Similar questions were asked after the initial announcement of what would become the dearMoon project. The earliest announced version was a lunar flyby on a Dragon 2 launched by a Falcon Heavy, both of which had yet to fly.
Speculation by Wayne Hale, esteemed veteran of the Space Shuttle program, as shared by Scientific American, was (emphasis mine)

A capsule that flies around the moon will need a more robust communications system and a more capable heat shield than a craft that just goes to low Earth orbit and back, he noted. (During Monday's teleconference, Musk said that communications modifications will indeed be necessary for the lunar fly-around, but he added that the baseline Dragon V2's heat shield is "quite massively overdesigned" and can handle the higher-velocity re-entry of a moon mission.)

Presumably there would also be some major changes to the flight software for such a mission.
It's not clear to me if the subsequent flight record of the Dragon 2 would change the conclusion about the heat shield; I'm not aware of any underperformance concerns brought up.  For my money I think I'd have preferred to see lunar return performance of the heatshield validated uncrewed rather than with commercial passengers.
